# Get the exception that was thrown earlier in application c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a bit of middleware written that on a callback checks if the response is a 500. If it is a 500 I want to return the exception that was thrown. How do I get the exception that was thrown in the application?

Startup.cs

```
...
 app.UseMiddleware<APIExceptionMiddleware>();

// Add MVC to the request pipeline.
app.UseMvc();
...
```

APIExceptionMiddleware.cs:

```
public class APIExceptionMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public APIExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.OnStarting(
                callback: (state) =>
                {   
                    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse)state;
                    if (response.StatusCode == 500)
                    {
                        // want to grab exception here turn it into JSON response place it in the response.Body but not sure how I access the exception.
                        return response.WriteAsync("An Error Occured");
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                }, state: context.Response);


            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
```

So as the request goes into UseMvc() I have an exception that is thrown. I can use app.UseDeveloperException(); and get a nice friendly HTML page with the stacktrace and exception.

I want to almost repeat that but make it a nice friendly JSON api response for my application. SO if a 500 is thrown I am using middleware to where I am going to turn that into a pretty json response and send it out as my response through the api request. My problem is how do I fetch this exception in the middleware?

If UseDeveloperException() is doing it shouldn't I be able to as well?

Comment: there is no context.Error

Comment: You mean there is no exposed property or it's null?

Comment: There is no context error property.

Comment: is Server.GetLastError() in scope?

Comment: No sure is not, because this is Kestrel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the code for [DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/4e5c99fabc6afdc67a181fad2b7d20ec59ab4225/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/DeveloperExceptionPage/DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.cs)... in particular look at `Invoke(HttpContext context)` (shown below).  Instead of using this default middleware that you are currently adding, use your own which you've started.  It will be very much like `DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware`: catch any exception, but instead of returning an error page just format your JSON response as desired.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(0, ex, "An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request");

        if (context.Response.HasStarted)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("The response has already started, the error page middleware will not be executed.");
            throw;
        }

        try
        {
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.StatusCode = 500;

            await DisplayException(context, ex);

            if (_diagnosticSource.IsEnabled("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.UnhandledException"))
            {
                _diagnosticSource.Write("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.UnhandledException", new { httpContext = context, exception = ex });
            }

            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            // If there's a Exception while generating the error page, re-throw the original exception.
            _logger.LogError(0, ex2, "An exception was thrown attempting to display the error page.");
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: keep in mind that leaking information about your system is a security risk

Comment: Yeah I have a certain few handful I want passed not all of them. I will use a decision to pass those I want ignore the others. Thanks!